# Device rooted by Seller?

Tags: root-access

My nephew parents had bought their son a new tablet, and while I snooping around his device and checked about tablet's information, I saw under kernel version option, it has:

```
root@tom-desktop #116
```

Does this mean the seller has rooted the device?

Comment: what kind of tablet?

Comment: @nullmem some unknown brand tablet known as "Smart"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly normal for a device (usualy import models from China) to have a kernel version such as "kernel version-- 3.4.0 root@tom-desktop#1" etc. and this has nothing to do with "rooting" a device. If I am not mistaken the "tom-desktop" is the default hostname when building a kernel.

Comment: I got myself a tablet imported from china, but just surprised it don't have anything else stated in kernel version. But I guess your right. +1 up